# Inactive resources

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, resources

How can I make a resource appear 'Inactive'? I see the 'Inactive' button on the 'Resource information', however it's disabled.

I have a resource that's been working on a project, but is no longer in the company, so I'd want him to show on the past tasks but not be available in the Resource pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Inactive command only works if you are using Project Server.  You don't want to remove the resource from the pool if she/he has logged actual hours.  The best I can suggest is to change the resource's name to "Jane Smith - DO NOT USE" or something like that.

Then routinely check the resource usage view to ensure Jane is not assigned to any tasks.

Comment: Thank you Julie, your advice about renaming sparked another idea - I made an 'Inactive' group and then moved those resources in there. This way they're noticeably distinct in the Resource usage view.